# Skype and Gtalk crash but Ventrilo works

Tags: windows-7, crash, skype, google-talk, ventrilo

"Skype crashes and ends up crashing all the other applications. Gtalk works fine except when i make a call. This happens on both of my laptops. Anyone know what the reason could be? I haven't been able to use Skype for months now."

This was my original question above ..

Tried using ventrilo and it works perfectly with no crashes however it only happens with gtalk and skype. So it cannot be a driver issue i guess ?

Answer (score 0):

Both Skype and Google-Talk have video chat capability and therefore attempt to access video hardware. Have you checked if maybe your have a bad webcam driver? Does using other webcam-related software crash, too?